# Is it possible to create a Sql Server Report (using SSRS) based on a linked database?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a Sql Server 2005 with SSRS configured on a local server. 
Then, we have on the same server a Linked Server to a Sql 2012 on a remote server.

I would like to do a report based on a db on the linked sql 2012, but i can't neither to connect ...

So, is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you connecting to the 2012 server directly or do you need to go through another server first?

If you can connect to the 2012 server, you can just use the Data Source Connection Properties to connect to the server.

[image]

If you are using a **Linked Server** to get to the other server, you would set the connection to the server and a database. Then you would need to include the linked server reference in the name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM LINKED_SERVER_NAME.DATABASE_NAME.dbo.TABLE_NAME
```